# whats the swift equivalent of NSObject<Protocol>?

Tags: swift, protocols, nsobject

I have a class that needs to be set with a variable of a NSObject subclass and that implements a certain protocol.

```
protocol ProtoTest {
    var foo: Int { get set }
}


class AClass: NSObject,  ProtoTest {
    var foo: Int = 3
}


class BClass: NSObject,  ProtoTest {
    var foo: Int = 4
}

class Consumer {

    var protoInstance: ProtoTest?  //Does not cary any information of the class just the protocol
    var protoInstance2: protocol<NSObjectProtocol, ProtoTest>?

    init(x: ProtoTest) {
        self.protoInstance = x
        self.protoInstance2 = nil
    }

    init(x: protocol<NSObjectProtocol, ProtoTest>) {
        self.protoInstance2 = x
        self.protoInstance = nil
    }

    func doSomething() {
        if let x = protoInstance {
            x.copy() //'ProtoTest' does not have a member named 'copy'
        }
        if let x = protoInstance2 {
            x.copy()    //protocol<NSObjectProtocol, ProtoTest> does not have a member named 'copy'

        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, neither declarations of the variable are gonna work. since neither of them have any knowledge of a base class?

How do I implement this in swift ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a couple of ways. First, you can make `Consumer` generic:

```
class Consumer<T: NSObject where T: Prototest> {
    var protoInstance: T?
    var protoInstance2: T?
}
```

If you do that, then all references to `protoInstance` or `protoInstance2` will inherit from `NSObject`, and you will be able to call methods like `.copy()` directly on the object.

If you don't want `Consumer` to be generic, you can enforce restraints on the `init` methods using generic parameters, like this:

```
class Consumer {
    // ...
    init<T: NSObject where T: Prototest>(x: T) {
        protoInstance = x
    }
}
```

If you do that, you will be guaranteed that `protoInstance` will be an `NSObject`, but you will have to cast to `NSObject` to use any of `NSObject`'s methods:

```
func doSomething() {
    if let x = protoInstance as? NSObject {
        x.copy()
    }
}
```

Edit:

Note that I wasn't sure if you really wanted `protoInstance` and `protoInstance2` to be of different types I was a little unclear from your question. If you do want them to be different types, I can add additional suggestions to this answer.

Comment: Thank you Roman, So you don't think there is a way to enforce NSObject in the variable declaration ?

Comment: You could define the variable as `var protoInstance: NSObject?` and then cast to `Prototest` when you want to use it. But if you want to enforce that the property is both an `NSObject` *and* a `Prototest`, then you're gonna have to use generics somewhere...

Comment: @EdwardAshak "So you don't think there is a way to enforce NSObject" Why do you imagine you would need to do that?

Comment: Putting generic constraints on all of your `init` methods ensures that the variables will only be initialized with `NSObject` types, though. So even though the variable isn't constrained to `NSObject`, as a practical matter you can always cast to `NSObject` and be assured that the cast will succeed.

Comment: This variable is initialized with AClass type object which is a subclass of NSObject and implements the protocol. I'm allowing the variable to be set to any object equivalent to AClass in definition which at some point is regarded to as NSObject as well. I hope this clarify things a bit

Comment: No, it didn't. :) What does "is regarded as NSObject" actually mean?

Comment: Maybe the generic option is the closest thing to my needs. I'll try and see how it works out.

Comment: Actually I can't event use the generic option in this case since its a UIViewController and it will just make the case an even more complicated than it is unfortunately

Comment: Are you merely talking about the `copy` call?

Comment: If you could perhaps clarify your question, stating exactly what it is that you are trying to do, we could offer a better solution. I have used generic parameters to represent `UIViewcontroller`s that support specific protocols before, so there is a way to do what you want. We just don't know what you want...

Answer (score 2):

The *usual* equivalent of `NSObject<Protocol>` in Swift is simply `Protocol`. Typically, this protocol is declared as a *class protocol* to guarantee that it will be adopted by a class.

If you also need the NSObject protocol methods (such a `respondsToSelector:`, then make Protocol adopt NSObjectProtocol.

If the problem is merely that you want to call `copy()` and you can't persuade the compiler to let you do it, then adopt NSCopying as well (or just use `respondsToSelector:` and `performSelector:` to bypass the compiler altogether).